# <div> renders with unexpected height, and breaks layout when empty

Tags: css, layout, html, height

Context: This is the output html of a wordpress theme I'm working on.

Everything seemed fine with the layout until I inspected the `<div id="foot">`(footer), I realized it's height is the whole page, I was expecting it to be just the size of it's content.

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/4/embedded/result/) ([code](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/4/light/)).

Trying to debug the issue, I came upon the realization that if I removed the content of the div or removed the div, it breakes the rest of the desing, why is that?

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/5/embedded/result/) ([code](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/5/light/)).

I was expecting the footer (`<div id="foot">`) to be the height of it's content, this seems to work fine if I add another div after the `#foot`:

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/6/embedded/result/) ([code](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/6/light/)).

I'm not sure why removing `#foot` messes the other content and I'm not sure why `#foot` is being rendered with a height (to the top of the page).

Comment: you need to simplify your question...cuz it's hard to figure it out what you actually need

Comment: @Mr.Alien You might be right, but it's hard for me because I'm not sure what the problem is. I'll edit my question but to clarify a little more, I'm asking why is the div with the id "foot" not the height of it's content's (like the div with other on the las example) but rather it's height is the whole page. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question now. You have a float, but the foot div doesn't clear it.

You need to add...

```
clear: both;
```

...or...

```
clear: left;
```

...to the `#foot` CSS to clear that left float above it. Otherwise the content will wrap around your footer.

Here's an update to your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/7/), showing the foot in proper position.

Side note, I believe you haven't closed all your div elements.

Comment: No, sorry if the question was not clear enough, but I don't need the footer to be completely at the bottom. I'm asking why foot is rendered with a height as tall as the possible while I was expecting it to be only as high as it's content. Is it clearer now? Thanks for the effort anyway :)

Comment: @trufa I updated my answer now that I understand your question.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you so much. I'll check which answer came firs (yours or Mr. Alien's and accept correspondingly) but for now +1 :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok now I got what you were actually asking, I would like the others to clarify what you were actually asking, that it was a problem of `floats`, I changed the background and I realised what was the actual thing here

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/10/)

[**Solved Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aRguA/9/)

Just Add this line above `footer` div to clear your floats, just used red color to show you the difference

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div id="foot">
    footer
  </div>
```

Comment: Damn it, feels so obvious now, I can't thank you enough! :) You've been really helpful.

Comment: BTW, you have my +1 but I'll have to check which answer came first and and I'll accept that one. Thanks!